# jquery .live function throwing error "Object [object Object] has no method 'live'"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I was trying to add a `click` event to a div Id in my project but it's throwing an error. I do not know why. Could some one please have a look at the code?

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header1">
        <input type="button" value="Search and Highlight!!" style="position: absolute; right: 100px; top: 10px;" />
    </div>
...
```

jQuery:

```
  var searchAttachPoint = document.querySelector('.header1');
  $('#header1').live("click", function () {
      myNameSpace.searchPrompt("Key the text and press Ok", false)
  }); // The error is thrown in this line
  var attachpoint = document.querySelector('.buttonAttachPoint');
  $(document).on('load', myNameSpace.LoadAllBooks("ajax/metadata.json", this.attachpoint));
```

Comment: what version of Jquery are you using? `live` was removed in Jquery 1.9, http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: What are those `querySelector` things used for?

Comment: @Bergi I've never seen those before... after a quick google, it appears that it's the 'native' JS method that jQuery/sizzle uses to select elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelector

Comment: @jammypeach: I know what they do, I was asking the OP what he tries to use them for (as he seems to do it wrong).

Comment: @Bergi excuse my presumption :)

Answer (score 1):

`.live()` is depreciated and can be replaced with `.on()`

so,

change: `$('#header1').live('click',function(){...})`

to: `$('body').on('click','#header1',function(){...})`

`body` should be replaced by the nearest static parent of `#header1`

Comment: You could even use `$("#container")` instead of `$("body")` to help narrow the target. That just depends on whether `#container` is static or not

Comment: Ideally the parent of #header1

Comment: good point, I'll add that to my answer